# Delegated Admin - Can create new fields?

Tags: delegate

Can a delegated admin create new fields, i know they cannot create new profiles, roles or modify the OWD.but someone please confirm if the delegated admin can create a new field?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, they can't.

To create fields they need ***Customize Application*** privilege on their profile. But if you add that permission they will be able to the *entire setup options*.

Comment: Thanks...i was almost positive that they cant, but still wanted to double check. Again thanks for your quick feedback.

Comment: I think if the delegate admin is having access to that object, then he/she can create fields as well even if he/she is not having Customize Application privilege on their profile